# I cannot aggregate record values grouped by year R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, statistics

I have two columns. The first column is called `gdp_per_year` which is the gdp in that particular year.
The second column is `year`. This is the respective year.

The values in `gdp_per_year` are in format e.g `1,032,023,232` so there are commas used as thousand separators.
I have tried many different ways of fixing this issue but so far I could not figure it out. I have tried different codes to aggregate and group based on unique values. I have also removed the `,` from the values and replaced them with `.` and with blank.

I have converted values from character to integer and it still doesn't work.

```
gdp_per_year <-  Suicides %>% select(gdp_per_year, year)
```

Converting this to integer.

```
gdp_per_year$gdp_per_year <-             
as.integer(as.character(gdp_per_year$gdp_per_year))
```

Testing if number is integer as its not adding up

```
typeof(gdp_per_year$gdp_per_year)
```

It is integer

#### First try:

```
total_gdp_per_year <- aggregate(gdp_per_year$gdp_per_year, 
by=list(year=gdp_per_year$year), FUN=sum)

aggregate(gdp_per_year$gdp_per_year, 
by=list(gdp_per_year=gdp_per_year$year), FUN=sum)

print(total_gdp_per_year)
```

But this resulted in an error

#### Second Try:

```
gdp_per_year %>% 
group_by(year) %>% 
summarise(gdp_per_year = sum(gdp_per_year))
```

What I need is the sum of `gdp_per_year` values grouped by the respective years. So at the end, I should not have double entry values for years. `gdp_per_year` should be summed up accordingly with their years. All year values must be unique.

[This is the Error I receive by inputting this code below. There are multiple random values for gdp_per_year missing and there are duplicate values for same year. E.g, 1994 appearing more than once.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GZrE.png)

## CODE USED WHICH GAVE ERROR 1 SCREENSHOT BELOW

```
gdp_per_year %>%
mutate(gdp_per_year = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", gdp_per_year))) %>%
group_by(year) %>%
summarise(gdp_per_year = sum(gdp_per_year))
```

## result of running dput(head(gdp_per_year))

```
structure(list(gdp_per_year = c("2156624900", "2156624900", "2156624900", 
"2156624900", "2156624900", "2156624900"), year = c(1987L, 1987L, 
1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try `gdp_per_year %>% 
dplyr::group_by(year) %>% 
summarise(gdp_per_year = sum(gdp_per_year))`

Comment: Hi Cem, can you edit your post with the output of `dput(head(gdp_per_year))`    ?

Comment: Hi Suliman. I tried this, also got the same error. Got multiple missing values for gdp_per_year and the year numbers are not unique. They appear more than once still. E.g 1998 appears more than once.

Comment: Hi Rohit, her e it is. I will also paste into description. structure(list(gdp_per_year = c("2156624900", "2156624900", "2156624900", 
"2156624900", "2156624900", "2156624900"), year = c(1987L, 1987L, 
1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Hi, this is very strange: in the data you have provided there are no `,` in the `gdp_per_year` column. Are you sure this is the right data?

Comment: All good! :) It worked. Just tried it again, and somehow worked!! :) Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could tell you are facing two issues.
First you have to transform `gdp_per_year` into numeric. This can be done by deleting  every `,` and then using `as.numeric` on the result.

Second, the aggregation can be done with `dplyr` as you showed in your second try.

So this could work:

```
gdp_per_year %>%
  mutate(gdp_per_year = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", gdp_per_year))) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(gdp_per_year = sum(gdp_per_year))
```

Comment: Selam :) So, I just tried the code, and got an error still. Now what is happening is, it is deleting random values of gdp_per_year and keeping others. The years have not grouped up either. I will try add a screenshot in the description.